# Loop a list with a Tuple C#

Tags: c#, .net, list, tuples

I have a list in C# called `MyList`:

```
List<Tuple<string, int, int>> MyList= new List<Tuple<string, int, int>>() 
        {
           Tuple.Create("Cars", 22, 3),
           Tuple.Create("Cars", 28, 5),
           Tuple.Create("Planes", 33, 6)
        };
```

I want to loop through the whole list in the same order as I filled it above and be able to get the values one by one for each list item, like `Cars, 22, 3`. How do I do that? I guess I have to use `ForEach` somehow.

Comment: You would generally write a loop in order to loop over a collection, yes.  What have you tried and what didn't work?

Comment: A loop is indeed what you would need!

Comment: You can switch to named tuples, it's more clear and readable

Comment: I know that I need a loop. But I don't know how to write it. This is what i did:


´            MyList.ForEach(Tuple<string, int, int> tuple)
            {

                

            };`

Comment: @KGB91 that's not a loop. That's an attempt to use the `ForEach` method with an incorrect lambda syntax. `foreach(var ... in MyList){ ... }` is a loop

Comment: @KGB91 you can use simple `for` loop as it is in my answer  below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use simple `foreach` loop for that, `Item1`, `Item2` and `Item3` represent an unnamed tuple items with corresponding types

```cs
foreach (var item in MyList)
{
    string name = item.Item1;
    int value = item.Item2;
    int something = item.Item3;
}
```

You can also switch to [named tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples#named-and-unnamed-tuples), which are available from C# 7. They are more readable and allow to define a custom name for tuple item and use a deconstruction

```cs
var MyList = new List<(string name, int value, int someting)>()
{
    ("Cars", 22, 3),
    ("Cars", 28, 5),
    ("Planes", 33, 6)
};

foreach (var item in MyList)
{
    var name = item.name;
    var value = item.value;
}
```

Comment: It works but I get `the type or namespace name 'ValueTuple' does not exist in the namespace 'System` when using named tuples.

Comment: @KGB91 it's available from C# 7 and .NET 4.6.1. You can try to install [System.ValueTuple](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ValueTuple/) package, if you don't have it from the box

Comment: @KGB91, you can use my answer which is more simple.

Comment: Yeah but it is easier to fill the tuples with this code :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be more declarative about what your values are you can explicitly set them in a foreach loop like this:

```
List<Tuple<string, int, int>> myList= new List<Tuple<string, int, int>>() 
        {
           Tuple.Create("Cars", 22, 3),
           Tuple.Create("Cars", 28, 5),
           Tuple.Create("Planes", 33, 6)
        };    

foreach ((string type, int fuel, int amount) vehicles in myList) {
        string item1 = vehicles.type;
        int item2 = vehicles.fuel;
        int item3 = vehicles.amount;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an easy to understand and simple solution that will help you.
You can use a `for` loop.

- Item1 (`string`),
- Item2 (`int`),
- Item3 (`int`)

are the `Tuple` `Items` in the order and in the format that you have placed them.

And the code below is the `loop`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < MyList.Count; i++)
{
     string item1 = MyList[i].Item1;
     int item2 = MyList[i].Item2;
     int item3 = MyList[i].Item3;
}
```